# Flask application Docker ngnix

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I've built 2 Docker images containing a Flask app (web container) and the other image (nginx container) containing Nginx as loadbalancer.

using docker-compose up and scale command:

```
docker-compose up --scale web=2
```

The result:

```
Starting dockerflaskloadb_web_1 ... done
Creating dockerflaskloadb_web_2 ... done
Starting dockerflaskloadb_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to dockerflaskloadb_web_1, dockerflaskloadb_web_2, dockerflaskloadb_nginx_1
web_1    | [2018-08-22 11:27:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
web_1    | [2018-08-22 11:27:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web_1    | [2018-08-22 11:27:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_1    | [2018-08-22 11:27:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
web_2    | [2018-08-22 11:27:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
web_2    | [2018-08-22 11:27:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web_2    | [2018-08-22 11:27:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_2    | [2018-08-22 11:27:21 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
```

this is what I get with some get requests in Flask app:

```
nginx_1  |  [22/Aug/2018:11:33:31 +0000] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 5640 "http://192.168.99.100/about" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" -172.22.0.4
nginx_1  |  [22/Aug/2018:11:33:33 +0000] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 5640 "http://192.168.99.100/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" -172.22.0.4
nginx_1  |  [22/Aug/2018:11:33:33 +0000] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 200 3195 "http://192.168.99.100/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" -172.22.0.4
```

The application works fine but I want to know which container (web1 or web2) will be used for each request.

Is there any methods that I can use to show container ID in my flask app?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Container's hostname is by default the container id. So something like:

```
import os
id = os.environ['HOSTNAME']
```

Or

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```